# Travel to British Overseas Territory with US Travel Document (I-571)

Tags: visas

Can a person in the USA in possession of Green Card and US Travel Document (I-571) travel to British Virgin Islands for tourism for a week without having to go through the British Consulate in the USA / visa procedure? Person travelling has an expired Russian Passport which cannot be renewed in time for travel.

Comment: Good question!  According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_the_British_Overseas_Territories#British_Virgin_Islands), which cites TIMATIC, green card holders who are traveling directly from the US do not require a visa.  I could not find an official BVI source for that, though.

Comment: [Timatic tells me the same thing](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=XX&DE=VG&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=US&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX)... after I learned how to code the refugee/stateless "nationality". Note "arriving directly from the US mainland." So taking a ferry from USVI seems to be excluded. But again, I looked around quite a bit and could not find BVI government information.

Comment: @Ari did you call BVI? We are interested in the outcome.

Answer (score 1):

Although the USA Today is not a government institution, it seems the official page corroborates the information: you don't need a visa but you do need a valid passport.

[USA Today](http://traveltips.usatoday.com/permanent-resident-need-visa-virgin-islands-108645.html):

> Green card holders visiting the British Virgin Islands are granted entry without visas as long as travelers meet the standard travel requirements. Visitors are allowed into the islands for a month provided the correct documents are shown at a land or sea port of entry: a passport, proof of accommodations on the island such as a hotel reservation and proof of your return journey such as an airline ticket. **If you're a green card holder, you'll need to use a passport from your country of origin**.

Emphasis mine.

[BVI Tourism](http://www.bvitourism.com/entry-requirements) somewhat corroborates although doesn't mention a green card:

> European citizens need a valid passport to enter the British Virgin Islands.

Comment: Interesting. Timatic says the opposite, that you _don't_ need a passport if you have a green card.

Comment: *Very* interesting, a phone call is definitely in order.